# Raphael with TypeScript - Call signatures used in a 'new' expression must have a 'void' return type

Tags: raphael, typescript

I am a bit new to both JavaScript and TypeScript so this might be a simple mistake on my part. I am using Raphael 2.1.2 and the TypeScript definition file from https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped version 2.1. I have two simple lines of code:

```
    var canvas: HTMLElement = document.getElementById("SVGCanvas");
    var x = new Raphael(canvas, 800, 800);
```

Consistent with the example code I have seen, but typescript fails to compile it with the error below:

```
    Call signatures used in a 'new' expression must have a 'void' return type
```

Can someone impart some wisdom here?

Thanks in advance.
Tim

Answer (score 2):

That error is a bit misleading I admit. But the fix is not to use `new`.

```
var canvas: HTMLElement = document.getElementById("SVGCanvas");
var x = Raphael(canvas, 800, 800);
```

When in doubt about how to use a TypeScript definition always look at the tests: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/raphael/raphael-tests.ts#L3 because they are garanteed to compile fine (that is what they *test*).

**Update:** 
Verified that the TS definition is consistent with JS lib : http://raphaeljs.com/ . *Don't use `new`*

**Update2:**

For :

> but I get a runtime error - 'Raphael' is undefined

Make sure `raphael.js` is included (e.g. using a `script` tag) *before* your compiled TypeScript (the generated JavaScript).

Comment: I tried taking away the new keyword. It does compile, but I get a runtime error - 'Raphael' is undefined